Unclear template resolution
I was going through the exercises in this post https://www.slamecka.cz/posts/2021-03-17-cpp-metaprogramming-exercises-1/
First of all, I want to say huge thanks to the author. The problems were quite interesting, challenging, and engaging.
One part of the problem caused me some issues, and I don't really understand why.
/**
 * 18. Define Insert for Vector, it should take position, value and vector.
 * Don't worry about bounds.
 * Hint: use the enable_if trick, e.g.
 *   template<typename X, typename Enable = void> struct Foo;
 *   template<typename X> struct<std::enable_if_t<..something      about X..>> Foo {...};
 *   template<typename X> struct<std::enable_if_t<..something else about X..>> Foo {...};
 */

// Your code goes here:
// ^ Your code goes here

// static_assert(std::is_same_v<Insert<0, 3, Vector<4,5,6>>::type, Vector<3,4,5,6>>);
// static_assert(std::is_same_v<Insert<1, 3, Vector<4,5,6>>::type, Vector<4,3,5,6>>);
// static_assert(std::is_same_v<Insert<2, 3, Vector<4,5,6>>::type, Vector<4,5,3,6>>);
// static_assert(std::is_same_v<Insert<3, 3, Vector<4,5,6>>::type, Vector<4,5,6,3>>);

I started tackling this issue disregarding the hint from the author.
This was my first try.
template <int P, int I, typename V> struct Insert;

template <int P, int I, int F, int... N> struct Insert<P, I, Vector<F, N...>> {
  using type = Prepend<F, typename Insert<P - 1, I, Vector<N...>>::type>::type;
};

template <int I, int... N> struct Insert<0, I, Vector<N...>> {
  using type = typename Prepend<I, Vector<N...>>::type;
};

As an error message to this approach, the compiler complains about disambiguosity
E:\problems\main.cpp(212,20): error: ambiguous partial specializations of 'Insert<0, 3, (anonymous namespace)::Vector<4, 5, 6>>'
[build]   212 |     std::is_same_v<Insert<0, 3, Vector<4, 5, 6>>::type, Vector<3, 4, 5, 6>>);
[build]       |                    ^
[build] E:\problems\main.cpp(163,49): note: partial specialization matches [with P = 0, I = 3, F = 4, N = <5, 6>]
[build]   163 | template <int P, int I, int F, int... N> struct Insert<P, I, Vector<F, N...>> {
[build]       |                                                 ^
[build] E:\problems\main.cpp(167,35): note: partial specialization matches [with I = 3, N = <4, 5, 6>]
[build]   167 | template <int I, int... N> struct Insert<0, I, Vector<N...>> 

Then I read the hint, and thought, what if I just use std::conditional_t
template <int P, int I, typename V> struct Insert;

template <int P, int I, int F, int... N> struct Insert<P, I, Vector<F, N...>> {
  using type = std::conditional_t<
      P == 0, typename Prepend<I, Vector<N...>>::type,
      typename Prepend<F, typename Insert<P - 1, I, Vector<N...>>::type>::type>;
};

And this time I got a different error message
[build] E:\problems\main.cpp(178,36): error: implicit instantiation of undefined template '(anonymous namespace)::Insert<-3, 3, (anonymous namespace)::Vector<>>'
[build]   178 |       typename Prepend<F, typename Insert<P - 1, I, Vector<N...>>::type>::type>;
[build]       |                                    ^
[build] E:\problems\main.cpp(178,36): note: in instantiation of template class '(anonymous namespace)::Insert<-2, 3, (anonymous namespace)::Vector<6>>' requested here
[build] E:\problems\main.cpp(178,36): note: in instantiation of template class '(anonymous namespace)::Insert<-1, 3, (anonymous namespace)::Vector<5, 6>>' requested here
[build] E:\problems\main.cpp(222,20): note: in instantiation of template class '(anonymous namespace)::Insert<0, 3, (anonymous namespace)::Vector<4, 5, 6>>' requested here
[build]   222 |     std::is_same_v<Insert<0, 3, Vector<4, 5, 6>>::type, Vector<3, 4, 5, 6>>);
[build]       |                    ^
[build] E:\problems\main.cpp(173,44): note: template is declared here
[build]   173 | template <int P, int I, typename V> struct Insert;
[build]       |                                            ^

Could anyone please explain why I get these messages, why do they differ?

The purpose of std::enable_if is to suppress the instantiation of the wrong template via SFINAE. std::conditional chooses one type from two, but still instantiates the templates in both branches and hence cannot replace std::enable_if. Of course concepts should be preferred in C++20 and above.

@WeijunZhou in C++20 you don't need anything like that to implement that task. constexpr  functions could do the thing in almost sane manear. It's not the complete example, but the rest is just couple of wrappers

@Dmitry thanks for the example. It's definitely doable in one way or another. But here my question was not about how to do it (I had solved it by the time posting), but why doesn't the given example work?

For Insert<0, I, Vector<N...>> and Insert<P, I, Vector<F, N...>>, neither is more specialized than the other. Insert<0, 0, Vector<>> matches the first but not the second, and Insert<1,0,Vector<0>> matches the second but not the first.

@WeijunZhou well exactly, so there should not be any disambiguity, right?

@Dmitry of course I can, but what region are you interested in? https://godbolt.org/z/qGc4ehn8r in the code there are 3 pragma sections. Those are related to the question.

No. Both are applicable, but neither is more specialized, hence the ambiguity.

@arsdever informally speaking non of template <int I, int... N> struct Insert<0, I, Vector<N...>>  and  template <int P, int I, int F, int... N> struct Insert<P, I, Vector<F, N...>> are more specialized than the other. The first one has 0 as a default argument, but the second one has an additional non-template argument F(variadic templates are always less specialized). The formal description would involve the rules for function overloading, but basically compiler can't figure out what is better default 0 or additional F.

The code failed because the template specialization in general is too broad. you cant prevent this
template <int I, int... N>
struct Insert<0, I, Vector<N...>> {
    using type = typename Prepend<I, Vector<N...>>::type;
};

and this
template <int P, int I, int F, int... N>
struct Insert<P, I, Vector<F, N...>> {
    using type = typename Prepend<F, typename Insert<P - 1, I, Vector<N...>>::type>::type;
};

From matching P = 0 even though the second code is intended for recursion. If P = 0 then P = 0. You have to handle it manually.
An adequate solution for this is using std::enable_if to prevent the recursion specialization from matching with P == 0 when it eventually reaches the case where P = 0
// forward declaration of Insert with std::enable_if
template <int P, int I, typename V, typename Enable = void>
struct Insert;

// specialization for P > 0 for recursion
template <int P, int I, int F, int... N>
struct Insert<P, I, Vector<F, N...>, std::enable_if_t<(P > 0)>> {
    using type = typename Prepend<F, typename Insert<P - 1, I, Vector<N...>>::type>::type;
};


enable_if was exactly what I used for solving the puzzle, but I still don't get it. I used to have partial specializations for other tasks too, where you have specialization for the positional argument with exact value, and never had similar issues. I do understand that it can match both for P, but shouldn't it peek the first if P==0? Why?

"You have to handle it manually." - Well I do with my partial specialization, don't I?
